flutter white screen with flutter logo error
when I run my app with flutter run there is no error but on the screen side on my mobile emulator all I have is flutter logo on white screen
Launching lib\main.dart on sdk gphone64 x86 64 in debug mode...
Building with Flutter multidex support enabled.
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              5,6s
√  Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
I/flutter (13091): Server running on http://localhost:8080
I/WebViewFactory(13091): Loading com.google.android.webview version 113.0.5672.136 (code 567263637)
W/ziparchive(13091): Unable to open '/data/app/~~hDKdF0exkSGWYFQSV6oLSA==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_567263637-HalHqdBoeCvg3a87tG2CjQ==/TrichromeLibrary.dm': No such file or directory
W/ziparchive(13091): Unable to open '/data/app/~~hDKdF0exkSGWYFQSV6oLSA==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_567263637-HalHqdBoeCvg3a87tG2CjQ==/TrichromeLibrary.dm': No such file or directory
W/le.near_pay_app(13091): Entry not found
D/nativeloader(13091): Configuring clns-7 for other apk /data/app/~~hDKdF0exkSGWYFQSV6oLSA==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_567263637-HalHqdBoeCvg3a87tG2CjQ==/TrichromeLibrary.apk. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=ALL, library_path=/data/app/~~unFi2v0XPpxIAQ7os0JIaA==/com.google.android.webview-nNInCrod4HMLcMpye9F-cg==/lib/x86_64:/data/app/~~unFi2v0XPpxIAQ7os0JIaA==/com.google.android.webview-nNInCrod4HMLcMpye9F-cg==/WebViewGoogle.apk!/lib/x86_64:/data/app/~~hDKdF0exkSGWYFQSV6oLSA==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_567263637-HalHqdBoeCvg3a87tG2CjQ==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand
D/nativeloader(13091): Configuring clns-8 for other apk /data/app/~~unFi2v0XPpxIAQ7os0JIaA==/com.google.android.webview-nNInCrod4HMLcMpye9F-cg==/WebViewGoogle.apk. target_sdk_version=34, uses_libraries=, library_path=/data/app/~~unFi2v0XPpxIAQ7os0JIaA==/com.google.android.webview-nNInCrod4HMLcMpye9F-cg==/lib/x86_64:/data/app/~~unFi2v0XPpxIAQ7os0JIaA==/com.google.android.webview-nNInCrod4HMLcMpye9F-cg==/WebViewGoogle.apk!/lib/x86_64:/data/app/~~hDKdF0exkSGWYFQSV6oLSA==/com.google.android.trichromelibrary_567263637-HalHqdBoeCvg3a87tG2CjQ==/TrichromeLibrary.apk!/lib/x86_64, permitted_path=/data:/mnt/expand
W/le.near_pay_app(13091): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->isTagEnabled(J)Z (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/le.near_pay_app(13091): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->traceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/le.near_pay_app(13091): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->traceEnd(J)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/le.near_pay_app(13091): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceBegin(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
W/le.near_pay_app(13091): Accessing hidden method Landroid/os/Trace;->asyncTraceEnd(JLjava/lang/String;I)V (unsupported, reflection, allowed)
I/cr_WVCFactoryProvider(13091): Loaded version=113.0.5672.136 minSdkVersion=29 isBundle=false multiprocess=true packageId=2
I/cr_VariationsUtils(13091): Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/com.example.near_pay_app/app_webview/variations_seed_new"
I/cr_VariationsUtils(13091): Failed reading seed file "/data/user/0/com.example.near_pay_app/app_webview/variations_seed"
I/cr_LibraryLoader(13091): Successfully loaded native library
I/cr_CachingUmaRecorder(13091): Flushed 8 samples from 8 histograms.
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(13091): Compat change id reported: 183155436; UID 10190; state: DISABLED
D/AutofillManager(13091): Fill dialog is enabled:false, hints=[password, passwordAuto, creditCardNumber, creditCardSecurityCode, creditCardExpirationDate]
Syncing files to device sdk gphone64 x86 64...                     113ms

Flutter run key commands.
r Hot reload.
R Hot restart.
h List all available interactive commands.
d Detach (terminate "flutter run" but leave application running).
c Clear the screen
q Quit (terminate the application on the device).

A Dart VM Service on sdk gphone64 x86 64 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:62814/-foNdbhg8ME=/
The Flutter DevTools debugger and profiler on sdk gphone64 x86 64 is available at: http://127.0.0.1:9101?uri=http://127.0.0.1:62814/-foNdbhg8ME=/
D/CompatibilityChangeReporter(13091): Compat change id reported: 214741472; UID 10190; state: DISABLED
D/ProfileInstaller(13091): Installing profile for com.example.near_pay_app

why I have error do you guys have any idea?

I am using the physical device for debugging. I am also faced the white/black screen error.
I fixed it by the following steps

uninstall the old app in the device
flutter clean
flutter pub get
flutter run


No I use mobile emulator and tried your suggestion but my mobile emulator just show me a white screen with flutter logo

I done like all similar stuff like flutter clean cleanin cache deleting mobil emulator repairing gradle etc but I can only see white screen with flutter logo
